# Entity manager symfony 2

Tags: symfony

I'm still trying to use the cart bundle from sylius,

i'm getting this error

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to myproject\Cart\ItemResolver::__construct()         must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager, none given, called in     myproject\cache\dev\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 3625 and defined in myproject\Cart\ItemResolver.php line 19
500 Internal Server Error - ContextErrorException
```

in fact i have seen this in the debug stack trace

```
at ItemResolver ->__construct ()

protected function getcompany_CartItemResolverService()
{
return $this->services['company_item_resolver'] = new \myproject\Cart\ItemResolver();
}
```

i suppose there is a problem with my config.

my service.yml looks like that

```
company.cart_item_resolver:
class: myproject\Cart\ItemResolver
argument: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']
```

and my config.yml for doctrine looks like:

```
orm:
auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
entity_managers:
  default:
      mappings:
          ApplicationSonataUserBundle: ~
          SonataUserBundle: ~
          FOSUserBundle: ~
          companyBundle: ~
          ApplicationSonataMediaBundle: ~
          SonataMediaBundle: ~
          SonataNotificationBundle: ~
          ApplicationSonataNotificationBundle: ~
          SyliusCartBundle: ~
```

I don't have automapping enabled, i suppose my argument in services.yml should be false, but i don't manage to have it right.

Could you help me?

Comment: That's a typo. It should be `arguments` not `argument`

Comment: hey, i've been late to anwer, it is the right answer i found it. Just come back to give the answer but you gave it thx :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code in your `service.yml`:

```
company.cart_item_resolver:
    class: myproject\Cart\ItemResolver
    arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']
```

It should fix your issue. More info about Injecting Services: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#referencing-injecting-services

Comment: ty found it myself, and didn't see the answer, it was a typo, ty for your time hope it will help peoples